# MVC multiplication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to multiply 2 numbers in MVC

Here is the code

CONTROLLER

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication17.Controllers
{

public class leetController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /leet/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        decimal result = Decimal.Parse(Request["FirstNum"]) * Decimal.Parse(Request["Secondnum"]);
        ViewBag.Result = result;
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

VIEW

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
 </head>
<body>
<div>

        <form>

        First number: <input type="value" id="FirstNum" value=""><br>
        Second number: <input type="value" id="Secondnum" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Arvuta">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Vastus"></asp:Label>
            @ViewBag.Result
        </form> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String when i try to run the code

When I run the code and the line decimal result = Decimal.Parse(Request["FirstNum"]) * Decimal.Parse(Request["Secondnum"]); seems to be faulty.

Comment: Do you (want to) understand what is happening, or do you just want your code fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to use method parameters, instead of fetching from Request:

```
public ActionResult Index(decimal? FirstNum, decimal? SecondNum)
```

Second, check if values isn't null

```
if(FirstNum.HasValue && SecondNum.HasValue) {}
```

Third, try to change decimal to double

P.S. And for get it to work you should use either url like http://yourdomain.com/leet/Index?FirstNum=1&SecondNum=2 or form post method, then you should create action with [HttpPost] attribute

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the code straight after building it? 
If so, your initial values are used to execute the multiplication, which is "".

Make sure you either start the calculation by pushing a button, or by entering a default value in the value field.

```
   First number: <input type="value" id="FirstNum" value="0"><br>
   Second number: <input type="value" id="Secondnum" value="0"><br>
```

Otherwise you're effectively trying to multiply nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal firstNum;
decimal secondNum;
decimal result = 0;

if (Decimal.TryParse(Request["FirstNum"], out firstNum) &&
    Decimal.TryParse(Request["SecondNum"], out secondNum))
{
    result = firstNum * secondNum;
}

ViewBag.Result = result;
return View();
```

Comment: Not all code paths return a value error

Comment: I have updated my example in response to your comment.

Comment: The result stays at 0, no matter what 2 numbers I enter :(